# CakePHP - How To Iterate an Array and Compare Array Values With a Variable

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have this array from `$Infor = $this->StudentFeeUtil->getPaymentPlanDetails($currentSessionID); pr($Infor)`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [PaymentPlan] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [payment_plan] => 35
                [submission_date] => 2022-11-30
                [intake_id] => 1263
                [session_id] => 1019
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PaymentPlan] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [payment_plan] => 35
                [submission_date] => 2022-10-31
                [intake_id] => 1263
                [session_id] => 1019
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [PaymentPlan] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14
                [payment_plan] => 30
                [submission_date] => 2022-09-30
                [intake_id] => 1263
                [session_id] => 1019
            )

    )
  )
```

I would like to iterate through this array and compare the `submission_date` with the current date `$now = new DateTime();`. If current date, `$now` is less than or equal to `$submission_date` and `$currentBalance` is greater than 0, then do something. Basically, I want something like this:

```
// Check if student has balance
        if ($now <= $Infor[0]['PaymentPlan']['submission_date'] && $currentBalance > 0) {
            // Do something
            echo " Tell student to pay up balance!";
        } else if ($now <= $Infor[1]['PaymentPlan']['submission_date'] && $currentBalance > 0){
            // Do something 
            echo " Tell student to pay up balance!";
         } else if ($now <= $Infor[2]['PaymentPlan']['submission_date'] && $currentBalance > 0){
            // Do something 
            echo " Tell student to pay up balance!";
  }
```

How can I achieve this using `foreach()`? I am using CakePHP-2 and PHP5.6. I am not sure how best I can implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$now` is a date like `2022-08-20` or so, you can use foreach like below where `$row` is the value of each row(which is an array) and access the `submission_date` just like the usual array key access.

```
<?php

foreach($Infor as $row){
    if($currentBalance > 0 && strtotime($now) <= strtotime($row['PaymentPlan']['submission_date'])){
        // Do something
            echo " Tell student to pay up balance!";
    }
}
```